# Is there somewhere I can buy a 20.04 disk

Tags: apt, sound, 20.04

I updated my HP computer from 18 to 20.04.  Google Chrome crashes, I have no sound.  I have read thru many of the questions and tried the given solutions.  When I try command line nothing seems to work.  Someone suggested reinstalling from disk.  I downloaded and unetbootlin but because I cant do anything command line I cant create a bootable disk.  So is there somewhere I can buy a disk?

Comment: Should make another question with your computer make and model and some specs and explain what is the problem with your command line.  Give as much information as you can.  Should be able to use unetbootlin with just mouse clicks, don't need command line.

Comment: On prior LTS releases, LoCo's are usually sent media which is available on request, they usually require payment of costs outside of release parties (postage/handling) often charging a flat fee (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was $10 as I recall in AU for mailed thumb-drive) so that maybe an option. http://loco.ubuntu.com/   *This comment uses past-tense as I've noted the emails offering it this year, but could just be I missed it*

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?q=20.04+disk&safe=active&client=firefox-b-e&sxsrf=ALeKk01rglNyH9CGZ3vsnOaWeOedhFv33A:1591055150186&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjy62o5uHpAhVOPcAKHfkJCtkQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1278&bih=664 -i think this is what you want, i didnt quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places you can buy a DVD, or you may find it more useful to use a USB key.

- [Shop Linux Online](https://www.shoplinuxonline.com/)
- [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/) - Search for Ubuntu 20.04

A computer shop or a linux users group near you might help you out too.

Other places may be available depending on where you are living. Update your question with that info.